# Cool bulbs into a min 90C fixture with 60C wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, safety, light-fixture

I bought a light fixture that has a min 90°C warning.  The wiring leading up to the fixture is NM (60°C wire).  I was wondering if an easy workaround to this would be to install a newer, more energy efficient light bulb to keep the temperature of the wire down.

Is this a viable solution to this problem? The next option is to replace the last 2 feet of NM with wiring that is certified to 90°C.

Comment: Are you sure you mean "minimum" 90C?

Comment: Yes, its right on the box.. "MIN 90 C SUPPLY CONDUCTORS"

Comment: Are your sure you have 60°C wire? My admittedly outdated reference for Type NM cable under Construction Specifications, says essentially that conductors shall be rated 90°C but the allowed current shall be as for 60°C conductors.

Comment: I was under the impression that NM is 60°C and NM-B is 90°C

Answer (score 1):

That's not a good workaround.  Recessed Insulation Contact (IC) lighting fixtures have a target temperature of 90ºC in the junction box.  Kinda crazy, but that's what it is. [See NEMA Bulletin #92 (December 2005)](http://www.nema.org/Technical/Documents/Bull92.pdf) which reads:

> *When the dwelling’s existing wiring is rated 60ºC, install a junction
>   box approximately 18 inches away from the newly installed lighting
>   fixture and then run Type NM-B from the junction box to the fixture.*

Installing the energy efficient bulb will not meet code.  You'll be fine.  But how are you going to prevent the next owner from sticking a hefty bulb in there?

An alternative is to take that fixture back, find something with a GU-24 socket, and hope the vendor was smart enough to realize that GU-24 means lower heat.

Comment: My thoughts exactly wrt the next person..